# "des Bit" vs "des Bits", "die Bit" vs "die Bits"

Tags: noun, inflection, semantics, suffix

1. **Genitiv von "Bit".** Der Duden gibt sowohl "des Bit" als auch "des Bits" als korrekte
   Formen des Genitivs von "[das Bit](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Bit_Einheit_in_der_EDV)" (EDV) an.  Gibt es einen
   Unterschied in der Semantik oder in der Verwendung zwischen diesen
   zwei Formen?
2. **Plural von "Bit".** Mit Zahlen nutzen wir "Bit" oft ohne Endung "-s": "20 Bit Information gingen verloren", "128-Bit-Verschlüsselung". Mit Mengenangaben in Worten darf "-s" vorkommen: "Das Gerät konnte eine Million Bit/Bits abspeichern".
   Gibt's eine genaue Regel, wann die Endung "-s" im Plural hinkommt und wann nicht? Gibt es eine sonstige Verwendung für die endungslosen Pluralformen "die/der/den/die Bit"  (Nom./Gen./Dat./Akk.) außerhalb der Mengenangaben?

Comment: Danke fürs Aufgreifen des "lesbar machen". Ich sehe ein, dass es um nur zwei Aspekte geht. Für mich sieht es aus wie zwei "Textklumpen" mit versteckten Fragen, auch bedingt durch die vielen nötigen Hochkomma. Ob meine Lösung zum Ziel "lesbar" erreicht wird, entscheidet am Ende jeder / jede Fragend/e selbst. Wie eben geschehen.

Answer (score 7):

Betrachtet oder verwendet man ein Bit als eine *Maßeinheit*, dann darf es nicht im Plural stehen (Maß- und Währungseinheiten bekommen keinen Plural).

> Der Commodore Amiga arbeitete mit einer Busbreite von 16 Bit

Betrachtet man individuelle Bits, womöglich auch noch mit individuellen Bezeichnern, sollte man den Plural verwenden.

> Die Bits 2 bis 5 des Statusregisters geben den Interrupt-Level an

Vgl. Behandlung von "Glas Wasser" vs. "Gläser Wasser"

> Ich war so durstig, dass ich gleich mal zwei Glas Wasser trinken musste.

vs.

> Der Kellner brachte uns beiden zuerst zwei Gläser Wasser

(Für Bytes gilt übrigens genau dasselbe)

Comment: @MdAyq5: Falls Sicherheit besteht, dass die Antwort passt, geht immer ein markieren als "ist Antwort". Upvote von Antworten zur eigenen Frage hätte ich angenommen, dass das von Beginn an geht, offenbar doch nicht.

Comment: @tofro *(Für Bytes gilt übrigens genau dasselbe)* - Der Kellner brachte Euch zwei Bytes? (SCNR)

Answer (score 0):

Zur Frage 1:

Das Wort Bit kommt aus dem Englischen, und ist auch dort kein eigenständiges Wort, sondern die Verkürzung von "Binary Digit" (Binärezahl). Daher haben sich bei der Verwendung im Deutschen beide Formen, Bit und Bits, eingebürgert, auch wenn ich die Form des Bits plausibler finde.

Der Duden gilt zwar als Referenz der Sprache, passt sich aber auch an die tatsächliche Verwendung an und ist insoweit auch deskriptiv und nicht nur normativ.